# Creating Schematic Symbol in Xilinx ISE14.7

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I have used `sfixed` signals, using the `ieee_proposed` library in my design.

My design works fine, but now I want to create Schematic Symbol from `ISE14.7`(Under Design Utilities). I am getting an error saying that `ieee_proposed` is not found.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You probably need to compile it. Or turn on VHDL-2008 mode so that it is no longer necessary. Also, there is documentation for Xilinx at http://www.eda.org/fphdl/

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? Can you show us the code around that part?